# Access on running background process in PhoneGap with AngularJS and Ionic

Tags: cordova, background-process, cordova-3, angularjs-service, ionic-framework

I have a problem with a Geolocation Background Process (https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) in a phonegap project with angularjs and ionic. The process is running fine but I can't stop it sometimes.

If the app is running in foreground it is all working fine. But when I start the background service and then push the home button on my device (Samsung Galaxy S2) the process is running in background -> correct. And now I reopen the app and try to stop the background process, but at this time it does not work.

It seems that I haven't the correct instance of the process.

This is my code:

```
var bgGeo;

angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('LocationService', function($http, $location){
    function startBackgroundLocation() {
        var gpsOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy : true,
            timeout: 10000,
            maximumAge: 5000
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
            console.log('Location from Phonegap');
        },
        function (error){
            alert('error with GPS: error.code: ' + error.code + ' Message: ' + error.message);
        },gpsOptions);


        bgGeo = window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation;

        /**
        * This would be your own callback for Ajax-requests after POSTing background geolocation to your server.
        */
        var yourAjaxCallback = function(response) {
            ////
            // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the #finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
            //  and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your HTTP request is successful or not.
            // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
            //
            //
            bgGeo.finish();
        };

        /**
        * This callback will be executed every time a geolocation is recorded in the background.
        */
        var callbackFn = function(location) {
            alert('[js] BackgroundGeoLocation callback:  ' + location.latitudue + ',' + location.longitude);
            // Do your HTTP request here to POST location to your server.
            //
            //

            // This is never called in Android
            yourAjaxCallback.call(this);
        };

        var failureFn = function(error) {
            alert('BackgroundGeoLocation error');
        }

        // BackgroundGeoLocation is highly configurable.
        bgGeo.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
            url: apiUrl + '/position/', // <-- only required for Android; ios allows javascript callbacks for your http
            params: {                                               // HTTP POST params sent to your server when persisting locations.
               auth_token: localStorage.getItem('gcmToken')
            },
            desiredAccuracy: 10,
            stationaryRadius: 20,
            distanceFilter: 30,
            debug: true // <-- enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
        });

        // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.  The user will be tracked whenever they suspend the app.
        // wenn der Service bereits läuft, nicht mehr starten
        bgGeo.start();
    }

    function stopBackgroundLocation(){
        bgGeo.stop();
    }

    return {
        start: function(){
            init();
        },
        stop : function () {
            stopBackgroundLocation();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `LocationService.stop()` after the app is resumed, the background geolocation does not stop.
Does somebody know whats wrong or what I have to add? Thanks.

@Aleks: Maybe you know a solution?

Comment: Nowbody has a solution or at least an idea or a hint? Please this is really import because it is for my exam. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use now this function:

```
function stopService(){
  var bgGeoService = window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation
  bgGeoService.stop()
}
```

And it seems to work.
But there is another approach, see this link: https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/issues/48

Hope this helps.